# importar Array para outro arquivo node/express

Tags: javascript, array, node.js, express.js

Bom dia, estou tentando fazer uma tela de logout e preciso encaminhar o array "blackList" do arquivo login.js para o autenticação.js, segue os codigos:

login.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const routes = express.Router()
const LoginModel = require("../models/Login");
const Login = require('../public/js/login/login')
const Registrar = require('../public/js/login/registrar')
...
const blackList = [];
routes.post('/logout', function(req, res) {
    blackList.push(req.headers['x-access-token'])
    res.end();
})
module.exports = routes
```

autenticação.js:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

require('dotenv').config()
const verificaToken = (req, res, next) => {
    const blackList = [];
    const token = req.cookies.token;
    const index = blackList.findIndex(token)
    if (index !== -1) {
        return res.status(401).end();
    }

    if (!token) {
        res.status(403).redirect("/");
    }
    try {
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRETJWTWEBTOKEN);
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(401).redirect("/");
    }
    return next();
};

module.exports = verificaToken;
```

tentei fazer a importacao do array, mas nao consegui. seria possivel ?

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta com um [mcve] no lugar do código apresentado. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor proveito do site.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

cara, a sua função verificatoken() precisa ser chamada dentro da rota de logout, existe alguns ponto obscuros na sua questão, mas quando você cria uma função com os parametros req, res e next você meio que ta dizendo que essa função é um middleware, e no local que você esta usando o arquivo de rotas e esse middleware a ordem das chamadas vai afetar o seu código diretamente(pelo menos utilizando express), mas baseado na sua explicação do que você quer que o codigo faça, parece mais lógico criar uma função qualquer, chamar ela dentro da rota passando os parametros que você precisa como o sua array blackList faz o que precisar lá dentro, pega a resposta da função e da o seu retorno da rota.

Comment: Bom dia! eu até consegui resolver esse problema, salvei o token nos cookies do navegador e limpei os cookies na rota de logout, obrigado. porém estou com um erro agora que não consigo acessar o site com em dispositivos moveis, apenas no desktop, consegue me ajudar ? Gato! 

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/576646/erro-error-err-http-headers-sent-cannot-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-t